# Turn on all CPUs for all nodes on a cluster: snow/snowfall package

Tags: r, parallel-processing, cpu, snow, snowfall

I am working on a cluster and am using the `snowfall` package to establish a socket cluster on 5 nodes with 40 CPUs each with the following command:

```
 > sfInit(parallel=TRUE, cpus = 200, type="SOCK", socketHosts=c("host1", "host2", "host3", "host4", "host5"));
 R Version:  R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10) 

 snowfall 1.84-6 initialized (using snow 0.3-13): parallel execution on 5 CPUs.
```

I am seeing a much lower load on the slaves than expected when I check the cluster report and was disconcerted by the fact that it says "parallel execution on 5 CPUs" instead of "parallel execution on 200 CPUs". Is this merely an ambiguous reference to CPUs or are the hosts only running one CPU each?

EDIT: Here is an example of why this concerns me, if I only use the local machine and specify the max number of cores, I have:

```
 > sfInit(parallel=TRUE, type="SOCK", cpus = 40);
 snowfall 1.84-6 initialized (using snow 0.3-13): parallel execution on 40 CPUs.
```

I ran an identical job on the single node, 40 CPU cluster and it took 1.4 minutes while the 5 node, apparently 5 CPU cluster took 5.22 minutes. To me this confirms my suspicions that I am running with parallelism on 5 nodes but am only turning on 1 of the CPUs on each node.

My question is then: how do you turn on all CPUs for use across all available nodes?

**EDIT**: @SimonG I used the underlying `snow` package's intialization and we can clearly see that only 5 nodes are being turned on:

```
 > cl <- makeSOCKcluster(names = c("host1", "host2", "host3", "host4", "host5"), count = 200)
 > clusterCall(cl, runif, 3)
 [[1]]
 [1] 0.9854311 0.5737885 0.8495582

 [[2]]
 [1] 0.7272693 0.3157248 0.6341732

 [[3]]
 [1] 0.26411931 0.36189866 0.05373248

 [[4]]
 [1] 0.3400387 0.7014877 0.6894910

 [[5]]
 [1] 0.2922941 0.6772769 0.7429913

 > stopCluster(cl)
 > cl <- makeSOCKcluster(names = rep("localhost", 40), count = 40)
 > clusterCall(cl, runif, 3)
 [[1]]
 [1] 0.6914666 0.7273244 0.8925275

 [[2]]
 [1] 0.3844729 0.7743824 0.5392220

 [[3]]
 [1] 0.2989990 0.7256851 0.6390770     

 [[4]]
 [1] 0.07114831 0.74290601 0.57995908

 [[5]]
 [1] 0.4813375 0.2626619 0.5164171

 .
 .
 .

 [[39]]
 [1] 0.7912749 0.8831164 0.1374560

 [[40]]
 [1] 0.2738782 0.4100779 0.0310864
```

I think this shows it pretty clearly. I tried this in desperation:

```
 > cl <- makeSOCKcluster(names = rep(c("host1", "host2", "host3", "host4", "host5"), each = 40), count = 200)
```

and predictably got:

```
 Error in socketConnection(port = port, server = TRUE, blocking = TRUE,  : 
   all connections are in use
```

Comment: Some thoughts on this: (1.) `snowfall` limits the number of CPUs free to use to 32 per default. There is a command (`sfSetMaxCPUs`) to change this. (2.) To test wether or not you cluster works, the example job you used might have been inadequate. The job runs for a short time on one machine. It is actually reasonable to assume that communication between hosts doesn't save anything here.

Comment: As I understood you, you worry that the `cpus` argument might not be working, giving a number of `socketHosts`. You should benchmark this more thoroughly by making up a job that is reasonably CPU-intensive and low on memory and HDD. Then you try different combinations (one host, two hosts... 2 CPUs, 4, 8, 16...). This will give you a better foundation to judge wether or not your cluster is working. It's difficult to judge otherwise what performance cost is due to the cluster or merely the task (which might be too simple or posing false demands, hence raising the cost of parallel computing.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After thoroughly reading the `snow` documentation, I have come up with a (partial) solution.

I read that only 128 connections may be opened at once with the distributed R version, and have found it to be true. I can open 25 CPUs on each node, but the cluster will not start if I try to start 26 on each. Here is the proper structure of the host list that needs to be passed to `makeCluster`:

```
> library(snow);

> unixHost13 <- list(host = "host1");
> unixHost14 <- list(host = "host2");
> unixHost19 <- list(host = "host3");
> unixHost29 <- list(host = "host4");
> unixHost30 <- list(host = "host5");

> kCPUs <- 25;
> hostList <- c(rep(list(unixHost13), kCPUs), rep(list(unixHost14), kCPUs),               rep(list(unixHost19), kCPUs), rep(list(unixHost29), kCPUs), rep(list(unixHost30), kCPUs));
> cl <- makeCluster(hostList, type = "SOCK")
> clusterCall(cl, runif, 3)
[[1]]
[1] 0.08430941 0.64479036 0.90402362

[[2]]
[1] 0.1821656 0.7689981 0.2001639

[[3]]
[1] 0.5917363 0.4461787 0.8000013
.
.
.
[[123]]
[1] 0.6495153 0.6533647 0.2636664

[[124]]
[1] 0.75175580 0.09854553 0.66568129

[[125]]
[1] 0.79336203 0.61924813 0.09473841
```

I found a reference saying in order to up the connections, R needed to be rebuilt with NCONNECTIONS set higher (see [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-hpc/2012-May/001373.html)).